# Hacer un filtro en mi listbox buscar por palabra

Tags: c#, xml

Esto es un programa para mostrar el xml en un `listbox`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadSprites();
        list.Clear();
        foreach (String str in listBox.Items)
        {
            list.Add(str);
        }

    }



    private void LoadSprites()
    {
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("sprites.xml");
        xdoc.Descendants("furnitype").Select(p => new
        {

            id = p.Attribute("classname").Value,
            name = p.Element("name").Value

        }).ToList().ForEach(p =>
        {
            string ci = p.name + "- " + p.id;
            listBox.Items.Add(ci);
            string name = p.name;
            string id = p.id;


        });

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text.Trim()) == false)
        {
            listBox.Items.Clear();
            foreach (string str in list)
            {
                if (str.StartsWith(textBox1.Text.Trim()))
                {
                    listBox.Items.Add(str);
                }
            }

        }
        else if (textBox1.Text.Trim() == "")
        {
            listBox.Items.Clear();

            foreach (string str in list)
            {
                listBox.Items.Add(str);
            }
        }
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
}
```

¿Cómo hago para que me busque en todo el string? Es decir, que no empiece a buscar por la primera letra.

Answer (score 1):

Deberias mantener los datos en una lista a nivel del form y filtrar sobre estos para luego mostrar el resultado en la listbox

Algo como esto

```
public class sprite
{
    public string id {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<sprite> result = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadSprites();
    }

    private void LoadSprites()
    {
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("sprites.xml");
        result = xdoc.Descendants("furnitype")
                                    .Select(p => new sprite()
                                    {

                                        id = p.Attribute("classname").Value,
                                        name = p.Element("name").Value

                                    }).ToList();

        result.ForEach(p =>
        {
            listBox.Items.Add(p.name+"- "+ p.id);
        });

    }

    public void button1_Click(...)
    {
        if(result==null)
            return;

        var query = result.Where(x=> x.name.Contains(TextBox1.Text)).ToList(); 

        query.ForEach(p =>
        {
            listBox.Items.Add(p.name+"- "+ p.id);
        });
    }

}
```

como veras se crea una clase para poder tener los datos en la lista a nivel del form, asi podras usar estos datos para filtrarlo luego cuando ingrese algo en el textbox

Comment: Hola modifique el codigo me busca por la primera letra hay alguna manera de hacer que busque por todo el texto.

Comment: podrias usar el Contains() o sea var query = result.Where(x=> x.name.Contains(TextBox1.Text)).ToList();

Comment: edite la pregunta cambiando la forma de aplicar el filtro

Answer (score 0):

Partiendo del ejemplo de [Leandro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/17948/4499) he mejorado un poco lo que hace:

Algo como esto:

```
public class Sprite
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

En el form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    IList<Sprite> Sprites;

    public Form1() { InitializeComponent(); }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { LoadSprites(); }

    private void LoadSprites()
    {
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("sprites.xml");
        Sprites = xdoc.Descendants("furnitype")
                           .Select(p => new sprite()
                           {
                               id = p.Attribute("classname").Value,
                               name = p.Element("name").Value
                           }).ToList();
        Sprites.ForEach(p =>
        {
            listBox.Items.Add(p.name+"- "+ p.id);
        });
    }

    private void TextBox1_TextChanged(...)
    {
        listBox.Items.Clear(); // O listBox.Clear(), no recuerdo.
        try { 
            var v = result.Where(x => x.name.StartsWith(TextBox1.Text)).ToList();
            v.ForEach(p => { listBox.Items.Add(p.name+"- "+ p.id); });
        } catch { Sprites.ForEach(p => { listBox.Items.Add(p.name+"- "+ p.id); }); }
    }
}
```

Es una forma algo *sucia* pero, funciona, el evento se activa al escribir sobre el `TextBox`, a medida que el usuario vá borrando o escribiendo caracteres en el `TextBox`, los registros en el `ListBox` van cambiando.

Comment: Hola modifique el codigo me busca por la primera letra hay alguna manera de hacer que busque por todo el texto.